# Mysterious Direct2D Memory Leak with gradients

Tags: c#, graphics, memory-leaks, directx, direct2d

I have a C# application based on SharpDX. There is a scenario in which the user is allowed to edit linear gradients, but since I did not find a way to modify an `ID2D1GradientStopCollection` (a.k.a. `SharpDX.Direct2D1.GradientStopCollection`), I am simply disposing and recreating the gradient for every frame that the user adjusts the offset of a gradient stop.

However, I noticed that if I adjust the gradient stop enough times (i.e., drag it around for 10 seconds while the linear gradient is recreated 60 times per second), then I notice that the memory usage of my application balloons without bound. I am certain that I am calling `Dispose` on the gradient:

```
private void RecreateBrush()
{

    var old = (SharpDX.Direct2D1.LinearGradientBrush)NativeBrush;
    NativeBrushLock.EnterWriteLock();

    NativeBrush = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.LinearGradientBrush(
        Target,
        new LinearGradientBrushProperties
        {
            StartPoint = new RawVector2(StartX, StartY),
            EndPoint = new RawVector2(EndX, EndY)
        },
        ConvertStops());

    old.GradientStopCollection.Dispose();
    old.Dispose();

    NativeBrushLock.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

But my memory usage still continues to increase. Profiling the application with dotMemory reveals that the memory increase is all unmanaged memory, so I began to dig deeper, and used DebugDiag 2.0 to profile my application. DebugDiag's analysis pointed at `d3d11!NOutermost::CDevice::CreateLayeredChild+15f` as the culprit that was allocating all of that memory, with a "Leak Probability" of 100%.

What does this mean, and how do I get rid of the memory leak? As far as I can tell, I am disposing of all of the resources I am creating (the `ID2D1LinearGradient` and the `ID2D1GradientStopCollection`).

This is the stack trace that I gathered from WinDbg:

> d3d11!NOutermost::CDevice::CreateLayeredChild
>     d3d11!CDevice::CreateTexture2D_Worker+0x47e
>     d3d11!CDevice::CreateTexture2D+0xbf
>     d2d1!CD3DDeviceCommon::CreateTexture+0x4c
>     d2d1!CD3DSurface::Create+0xe1
>     d2d1!D2DGradientStopCollection::EnsureRealizedForBrushType+0x239
>     d2d1!D2DGradientBrush::SetGradientStopCollectionInternal+0x85
>     d2d1!D2DLinearGradientBrush::Create+0x8c
>     d2d1!DrawingContext::CreateLinearGradientBrush+0xce
>     d2d1!D2DDeviceContextBase::CreateLinearGradientBrush+0xe7
>     [Managed to Native Transition]
>     SharpDX.Direct2D1.RenderTarget.CreateLinearGradientBrush(SharpDX.Direct2D1.LinearGradientBrushProperties,
>   System.Nullable`1, SharpDX.Direct2D1.GradientStopCollection,
>   SharpDX.Direct2D1.LinearGradientBrush)
>     SharpDX.Direct2D1.LinearGradientBrush..ctor(SharpDX.Direct2D1.RenderTarget,
>   SharpDX.Direct2D1.LinearGradientBrushProperties,
>   SharpDX.Direct2D1.GradientStopCollection)
>     MyApp.Direct2D.LinearGradientBrush.RecreateBrush()
>     MyApp.Direct2D.LinearGradientBrush.OnStopsChanged(System.Object,
>   System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)

As you can see, I make sure to dispose of both the brush and the gradient stop collection (which seems to continue to exist when the brush is deleted). However, the native memory usage of my application continues to steadily increase, unclaimable by the CLR garbage collector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in my creation of the gradient stop collection: ConvertStops() yields a `SharpDX.Direct2D1.GradientStopCollection`. However, I need to make sure dispose of that gradient stop collection after calling the constructor of `LinearGradientBrush`, because while the returned `LinearGradientBrush` has a property `GradientStopCollection` that represents a **pointer** to the same value, it is not the same .NET **instance**. Therefore, disposing of it by retrieving it from the `LinearGradientBrush.GradientStopCollection` does not decrease the reference count to 0, and the data continues to exist.

The modified `RecreateBrush` method looks like this:

```
private void RecreateBrush()
{
    var old = (SharpDX.Direct2D1.LinearGradientBrush) NativeBrush;

    NativeBrushLock.EnterWriteLock();

    using (var nativeStops = ConvertStops())
        NativeBrush = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.LinearGradientBrush(
            Target,
            new LinearGradientBrushProperties
            {
                StartPoint = new RawVector2(StartX, StartY),
                EndPoint = new RawVector2(EndX, EndY)
            },
            nativeStops);

    old.Dispose();

    NativeBrushLock.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

Comment: It's good to know that the lifetime of the GradientStopCollection object is managed by the calling code, not the caller. However, I do not see how this would cause an unmanaged memory leak in your application in the long run, because the GradientStopCollection is a managed object from the SharpDX library. If not explicitly disposed, the garbage collector should dispose of it eventually, and if it correctly wraps the objects it holds, it should deallocate them then.

Comment: I have to confirm that not disposing the GradientStopCollection appears to cause uncontrollable memory leaks, which I still throw back to the developers of SharpDX: Why don't they get disposed automatically (and free their unmanaged resources) when going out of scope and the garbage collector runs?