# Is it possible to have permanent memory leak if failed to dispose?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I know its always a good practice to wrap every single `IDisposible` objects with `using`. But is it possible to create permanent memory leak like c++ if I failed to do so? (by permanent I mean the life time of the application)

I know GC will have a hard time with COM and native resources but lets assume I am using managed code only. No COM, no unsafe only built in packages and managed code. Is there any `IDisposible` that GC won't be able to collect even after the variable is out of scope?

Comment: There is always a risk that if `Dispose` wasn't invoked even if GC collects the object a connection to database let's say or smth else will remain open and will 'never' close. GC only invokes the destructor but we have no guarantee that it knows anything about the managed resources we use or how to dispose them

Comment: The garbage collector doesn't care about IDisposable one way or the other. If you want objects to be disposed for certain when they are garbage-collected then you must implement a finalizer. You should still dispose IDisposable things manually, though, because the garbage collector is not guaranteed to run.

Comment: It's possible in the sense that this all depends on what the type implementing IDisposable is doing. Technically, calling Dispose is not formally required, it is more the polite thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. When the GC collects an object, then the object's [finalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors) is run. In most implementations of `IDisposable`, `IDisposable.Dispose()` is called from the finalizer, which means that the object will be disposed when it is garbage collected.

However, sometimes this is not the case. For example, many objects in the [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) library are not disposed in their finalizers, so if you do not dispose them, then the native objects that they represent (in this case, graphics resources) will not be cleaned up and you will end up with a memory leak. This is actually the source of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876001/mysterious-direct2d-memory-leak-with-gradients/47888435) I had a while ago.

Edit: I didn't see that you mentioned no unmanaged resources. In that case, no. All C# code that doesn't depend on unmanaged code must depend on the BCL, which does not easily create memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. A common source of issues are Timers which when not disposed will keep a reference to your callback and keep your class which implements the callback and all associated data alive forever.

Besides unmanged objects another very common source are event registrations which are unregistered in the dispose method if no weak event pattern is used. That can become pretty cumbersome to manage which is the reason why WPF relies entirely on weak events to work around the lifetime issue. WPF Windows have no Dispose method. Lifetime is managed by the garbage collector entirely.

If you are working with WinForms on the other hand you will quickly notice what happens with if you forgot to call Dispose on some windows ...